# Can I get my Google Voice data from Google?

Tags: google, google-voice

Can I get a document showing any recorded messages that have been left on my Google Voice account?

I have been using the generic message since I established the account without even a name recording.

It would be very helpful to me to have a legal document showing this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Takeout](http://www.dataliberation.org/takeout-products/google-voice) to download an archive of your entire Google Voice account.